# How can you change the name of a JCR node?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I'm trying to change the name of a JCR node, but I have no idea how? Has someone of you some hints?

Many thanks.

Comment: are you trying to change the node's name "property" or the node's "type" name?

Answer (score 11):

The [Jackrabbit Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExamplesPage) provides an example:

```
void rename(Node node, String newName) throws RepositoryException 
    {
        node.getSession().move(node.getPath(), node.getParent().getPath() + "/" + newName);
        // Don't forget - not necessarily here at this place:
        // node.getSession().save();
    }
```

Comment: Note that the rename method is *not* part of JCR. It is part of the Jackrabbit API though. 
If you want to be strictly JCR compliant you need to use the move method to move a node to a new name. In addition, if the parent node is orderable, you have to reorder the moved node to its previous place after moving.

Comment: The wiki still maintains that code as the date of today, but testing that with JackRabbit's latest version throws an Exception. Removing the extra "/" is needed to make it work..