# renaming jcr nodes customly (in CQ/AEM)

Tags: java, aem, jcr

Authors make some comments **once a month**.

- It is stored in "content" in jcr under node "remarks".  each comment
  is stored in a child node which is named as"**remarks_xxxx**" where
  xxxx are random alphabets and numbers.
- I need to *rename all the    current nodes* to **"remarks_mmddyy"**
  and *also assign future names*    in a similar fashion.

Thanks

Comment: When the component is dropped, the node gets created. I cannot name the node at that point of time as the user needs to enter "date" while editing the component. Hence, the node has to be actually renamed after editing the component is done based on the author input. I know i haev to use listeners here but I have no idea where to start regarding renaming the nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to write the date of the remark into a property (of type Date) instead of writing it into the node name. This will eliminate the need to rename nodes and also improve your chances to leverage jcr queries to your advantage.

In order to retrieve remarks for a certain date and time use the [jcr query api](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/queries-and-indexing.html), which allows to search for properties (including Date format of course). Since AEM 6 and jackrabbit oak, you can define a custom index to make sure that a given property query is blazing fast in terms of performance. Note that "order by" is supported as well, in case that ordering is an issue.

In case that you absolutely must stick with the detrimental data model of renaming nodes and sticking dates into node-names, check out the following article how to do it: [How can you change the name of a JCR node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164995/how-can-you-change-the-name-of-a-jcr-node)